# Accessing Dropbox Core API Error Information iOS 8 Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

This app uses the Dropbox Core API to move files to Dropbox for backup storage. The upload and download processes work well. The delegate calls are made correctly and allow me to verify the upload and download processes when they succeed. But I have not been able to programmatically access the error information when an upload fails.

For example, if I delete the file to be uploaded, this code (a delegate method) yields the following console information, which includes the data I want - I just can't get it programmatically.

```
-(void)restClient:(DBrestClient *)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"File upload failed with error: %@,error);
NSLog(@"error data: %@", [error.userInfo objectForKey:@"sourcePath"]);
}
```

2014-12-03 20:33:03.178 BiopLog[43089:4749399] [WARNING] DropboxSDK:
File does not exist
(/path/Documents/BiopBak123.sqlite-shm)

```
2014-12-03 20:33:03.297 BiopLog[43089:4749399] File upload failed with
error: Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=1001 "The operation couldn’t be
completed. (dropbox.com error 1001.)" UserInfo=0x7fa9e2f814f0
{sourcePath=/path/Documents/BiopBak123.sqlite-shm, 
destinationPath=/BiopBak123.sqlite-shm
```

Comment: Your "NSLog(@"error data:..." looks right. In what way does it fail?

Comment: It doesn't fail. I just need to be able to extract the file name to compare with the list of expected results. Obviously, I could try to parse the entire error message but that seems pretty Neanderthal. I have to believe there is a way to call for just the sourcePath - I've tried many, many guesses but have not been able to do so. Just for completeness, that is easy for the success method.

Comment: So what happens when your "NSLog(@"error data:..." line is run? Your quoted log only seems to show the line before.

Comment: Wow. My error. I must have deleted that from the post. 2014-12-03 20:33:03.297 BiopLog[43089:4749399] error data: Error
Domain=dropbox.com Code=1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(dropbox.com error 1001.)" UserInfo=0x7fa9e2f814f0
{sourcePath=/path/Documents/BiopBak123.sqlite-shm, 
destinationPath=/BiopBak123.sqlite-shm}

Comment: Strange, I just tried your code from your question, and (after fixing "DBrestClient" -> "DBRestClient" and adding the missing " in the first NSLog) it worked as expected for me:
2014-12-05 11:42:03.581 core_sdk_test[52209:6913207] File upload failed with error: Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 1001.)" UserInfo=0x7f91b0c35a10 {sourcePath=/bad/path.txt, destinationPath=/Testing/path.txt}
2014-12-05 11:42:03.581 core_sdk_test[52209:6913207] error data: /bad/path.txt

Comment: If this is the actual code you were using, maybe it was the missing " throwing you off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do this the hard way - by parsing the error data. In this case, my code creates the filenames and I always use the same base and the same number of characters in the file name. This works, but I'd still like to know the more elegant approach.

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {

    //parse the error data for the file name
    NSString *fullErrorData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error];
    NSString *answer;
    NSString *message;

    if ([fullErrorData containsString:@"FileBase"]) {
        NSRange range = [fullErrorData rangeOfString:@"FileBase"];
        NSRange newRange = {range.location,21};//the known length
        answer = [fullErrorData substringWithRange:newRange];

        message = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"The upload for file %@ failed. The remnants will be automatically deleted. You may receive an error message about the deletion - dismiss it.", answer];
    } else {
        message = @"Could not determine the file upload that failed.";
    }

    UIAlertView *uploadAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Upload Failure" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Understood" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [uploadAlert show];

    //Add code to clear any remnants

}//restClient:uploadFileFailedWithError
```